# Python - Subprocess - Recording and Dumping Measurements

Tags: python, subprocess, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

In python3 with Ubuntu 16.04LTS, I have a subprocess that I created from my main script to record measurements from a device connected to my local machine. I would like to know how to send a message to this subprocess when I want to finish data recording, and switch to dumping the measurements to a csv file. Shown below is a stripped-down version of what I have tried so far, but the code hangs and I am unable to dump the measurements I record. In fact, I only record 1 measurement. I am not sure about how to asynchronously check for stdin inputs while recording data. May I please get some help?

***Main.py***

```
# start subprocess
p_1 = subprocess.Popen(["./ekg.py", saveFilename_ekg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# do other stuff
...

# send message to quit
message = str("1")
encMsg = message.encode()
print("Message:", encMsg.decode())

p_stdout = p_1.communicate(input=encMsg)[0]

# print "Done" from subprocess 
print(p_stdout.decode('utf-8').strip())

# kill subprocess
p_1.kill()
```

***ekg.py***

```
def dumpLiveData(outputFile):

    ekg = ekgClass()
    dataMeasurements = []

    for liveData in ekg.getLiveData():

        # monitor stdin for message
        if int(sys.stdin.read()) == 1:
            break
        else:
            meas = [liveData.time, liveData.pulseWaveform]
            dataMeasurements.append(meas)

    #print ("Dumping data")

    with open(outputFile, 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        #print ("Created text file")

        header = ["Time", "Waveform value"]
        writer.writerow(header)

        for idx, val in enumerate(dataMeasurements):
            writer.writerow(dataMeasurements[idx])    

    print("Done")


if __name__== "__main__":  

    # get parameters
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="ekg.py")
    parser.add_argument("outputFile", help="Output CSV file.")

    # parse
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # record and dump measurements
    dumpLiveData(args.outputFile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by sending a control + C event to the subprocess. An try-except-else block caught the keyboard interrupt, processed it, and then I gracefully exit the block. After exiting, I write the data recorded to a csv file.

***main.py***

```
import subprocess, signal 

# start subprocess
p_1 = subprocess.Popen(["./ekg.py", saveFilename_ekg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# do other stuff
...

# send control + C event
p_1.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

stdout, stderr = p_1.communicate(input=encMsg)[0]

# print output from subprocess 
print(stdout.decode('utf-8').strip())

# wait for subprocess to write file
p_1.wait()

# kill subprocess
p_1.kill()
```

***ekg.py***

```
def dumpLiveData(outputFile):

    ekg = ekgClass()
    dataMeasurements = []
    exception_found = None

    try:

        for liveData in ekg.getLiveData():
            if exception_found == True:
                break

            meas = [liveData.time, liveData.pulseWaveform]
            dataMeasurements.append(meas)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        exception_found = True

    else:
        pass

    print ("Dumping data")

    with open(outputFile, 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        print ("Created text file")

        header = ["Time", "Waveform value"]
        writer.writerow(header)

        for idx, val in enumerate(dataMeasurements):
            writer.writerow(dataMeasurements[idx])    

    print("Done")
```